# nmcli, teaming an ethernet and wireless for load balance and failover

Tags: centos, networking, nmcli

i got this 2 interfaces

```
ens33: connected to ens33
        "Intel 82545EM"
        ethernet (e1000), 00:0C:29:ED:XX:XX, hw, mtu 1500
        ip4 default
        inet4 172.16.89.129/24
        route4 0.0.0.0/0
        route4 172.16.89.0/24

wls35u1: connected to wifi1
        "Ralink RT5372"
        wifi (rt2800usb), 7C:DD:90:A9:XX:XX, hw, mtu 1500
        inet4 192.168.80.48/24
        route4 0.0.0.0/0
        route4 192.168.80.0/24
```

What i want to do is make a load balance between both internet connections, searched a lot and found that the easiest way is via teaming or bonding. 
Now, after a few tutorials, i managed to create a team and put the ethernet network on it (the wireless gives me an error), this is the commands i've used

```
nmcli connection add con-name team0 type team ifname team0 config '{"runner":{"name":"activebackup"}}' #this for creating the team interface

nmcli connection modify team0 ipv4.addresses 10.0.0.0/24 ipv4.method manual connection.autoconnect yes #this for giving the ip to the devices

nmcli connection add con-name team0-1 type team-slave ifname ens33 master team0 #this for slave ens33
nmcli connection add con-name team0-2 type team-slave ifname wls35u1 master team0 # this for slave wls35u1

nmcli c up team0 
nmcli c up team0-1 
nmcli c up team0-2 #this gives a common error with wireless card which i couldnt manage to fix yet
```

everything okay but when i try to ping google, both networks lost the internet connections,i thought i could fix it using any gateway in the team0 network, but it didnt fix it, this was the command i used

```
nmcli c modify team0 gw4 172.16.89.0 #the gateway for ens33
```

but it didnt work.
the question basically is **how do i make a load balance with team on both connections without disconnecting them to the internet, (and if it doesnt work that way) how should i approach this?**

and also a little extra, when i try  `nmcli c up team0-2` the output print `no suitable device found for this connection (mismatching interface name)` already tried disabling mac randomization and creating a new ifcfg file for this device

Im using centos 7

Comment: teaming (similarly to bonding) is intended to work at layer 2 and present a single interface to put an IP on it. The slave interface(s) must not have an IP (they can, but it will be ignored). So you should read documentation on what is teaming/bonding to understand you're probably not doing something which makes a lot of sense. Example: https://wiki.debian.org/Bonding (the laptop mode here makes sense only when the wireless LAN is the same as the ethernet LAN. And it's not for load balancing, but for failover only: unplugging the laptop should allow keeping the connections)